# Utilisation de tous et tout

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Voici les exemples que je suis encore troublée.

Les verres et les assiettes, elle a tous rangés.
 —->Ou tout? Parce que ça s’applique avec les choses comme

1.j’ai mangé des biscuits,j’ai tout mangé.

2.tout est bien, finit bien.

Et souvent on n’utilise pas tout pour remplacer les personnes 
—-> Ils sont descendus par là maintenant ils sont tous partis.

Si vous avez les exercices,s’il vous plaît, conseillez-moi. Merci beaucoup par avance.

Comment: J'ai tout mangé→*tout* est un pronom. J'ai mangé tous les biscuits→ *tous* est un adjectif (et donc s'accorde avec biscuits). Tout est bien qui finit bien→*tout* est un pronom. Les filles sont toutes parties, les garçons sont tous présents, les arbres sont tous morts, les fleurs sont toutes fanées, dans ces quatre phrases tous/toutes est adjectif avec accord avec le nom auquel il se rapporte. Voir [ici](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-14942.php). Tout peut aussi être un nom, on peut alors mettre le déterminant *le* devant : le tout coûte 3 euros.

Comment: Merci beaucoup 

Comment: Pour les exercices, par exemple : https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-18115.php

Answer (score 1):

On utilise tous quand on parle de plusieurs entités. 
En revanche on utilise tout quand on parle de la totalité d'une entité.

Answer (score 1):

« Tout » a généralement soit une fonction adjectivale ou adverbiale. S’il joue le rôle d’un adjectif, il peut être remplacé par : « entièreté, totalité. » *Tout*, en tant qu’adjectif, peut prendre la forme féminine si le nom qu’il qualifie est féminin, soit « toute ».

*Ex*

*- Je suis allé au parc toute la journée*.

(Je suis allé au parc **l’entièreté de la journée**)

« Tout », en tant qu’adverbe, peut être remplacé par d’autres adverbes de même nature, tels que : « entièrement, complètement, vraiment. »

*Ex*

*- Je suis **tout** content d’avoir passé mon examen !*

(Je suis **vraiment** content d’avoir passé mon examen !)

*- Je suis **tout** émue*.

(Je suis **entièrement** émue.)

ATTENTION

« Tout » en tant qu’adverbe ne s’accorde en genre que si le mot féminin qui suit commence par une voyelle.

*Ex*

*- Je suis **toute s**urprise.*

Quant à « tous, toutes », il s’agit là d’articles indéfinis qui renvoient à des quantités, donc fonction plurale.

*Ex*

*- J’ai terminé **tous** les projets.*

*- Elle prend **toutes** les mesures nécessaires.*

*- Vous devez répondre à **toutes** les questions.*

Un bon truc est de remplacer « *tous, toutes* » par d’autres articles comme « ***mes, tes, ces, des*** ». Si cela a grammaticalement du sens, il s’agit donc de forme indéfinie.

*- J’ai terminé **mes** projets.*

*- Elle prend **des** mesures nécessaires.*

*- Vous devez répondre à **mes** questions.*